# Loading custom objects with PyYAML

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml

I have the following YAML document:

```
!!com.example.hero.YAMLAnimals
animals:
  Land: [Cow, Lion]
  Sea: [Salmon, Cod]
```

I expected to be able to load the `animals` object by subclassing `YAMLObject`.

```
class YAMLAnimals(yaml.YAMLObject):

    yaml_tag = u'!com.example.hero.YAMLAnimals'

    def __init__(self, animals):
        self.animals = animals
```

However, when I load the document, I get a `ConstructorError`.

```
ConstructorError: could not determine a constructor for the tag 
    'tag:yaml.org,2002:com.example.hero.YAMLAnimals'
```

Comment: Saw this in the docs: `# In Python 3, do not use the 'u' prefix` 
Also, not a YAML expert, but noticed in your class there is only a single bang `!` in your string.

Comment: Possibly an open issue: https://github.com/yaml/pyyaml/issues/266

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [YAML Reference Card](https://yaml.org/refcard.html), using the double exclamation point prefix will add `tag:yaml.org,2002:` to the front of your tag. Instead, use a single exclamation point to properly define your tag.

```
Animals: !com.example.hero.YAMLAnimals
  Land: [Cow, Lion]
  Sea: [Salmon, Cod]
```

---

```
class YAMLAnimals(yaml.YAMLObject):
    yaml_tag = '!com.example.hero.YAMLAnimals'
```

---

Also, as [@mgrollins](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3911355/mgrollins) points out, you need to pass the `Loader` argument to `yaml.load`.

```
document = yaml.load(..., Loader = yaml.Loader)
```

---

```
>>> Animals = document['Animals']
>>> print(Animals)
<__main__.YAMLAnimals object at 0x1098c2dd0>
>>> print(vars(Animals))
{'Land': ['Cow', 'Lion'], 'Sea': ['Salmon', 'Cod']}
>>> print(Animals.Land)
['Cow', 'Lion']
>>> print(Animals.Sea)
['Salmon', 'Cod']
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [`yaml.add_constructor`](https://pyyaml.docsforge.com/master/api/yaml/add_constructor/) when defining your tag; along with a [`namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple).

```
class YAMLAnimals(collections.namedtuple('Animals', 'Land, Sea')):
    def __new__(cls, loader, node):
        return super().__new__(cls, **loader.construct_mapping(node))

yaml.add_constructor('!com.example.hero.YAMLAnimals', YAMLAnimals)
```

---

```
>>> document = yaml.unsafe_load("""
... Animals: !com.example.hero.YAMLAnimals
...   Land: [Cow, Lion]
...   Sea: [Salmon, Cod]
... """)

>>> print(Animals := document['Animals'])
YAMLAnimals(Land=['Cow', 'Lion'], Sea=['Salmon', 'Cod'])

>>> print(Animals._asdict())
{'Land': ['Cow', 'Lion'], 'Sea': ['Salmon', 'Cod']}
```